# jQuery Flip! plugin for text only?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, flip

Any way to make the famous jQuery Flip! plugin affect the text only? ... as in seeing the text actually rotate rather than just disappearing and then re-appearing at the end of the "rotation"?

```
var $flipBox  = $('span#flipbox'),
    flip_opts = [{
        direction: 'tb',
        speed: 600,
        content: "NUMBER TWO"
    },
        {
            direction: 'tb',
            speed: 600,
            content: "NUMBER 3"
        },
        {
            direction: 'tb',
            speed: 600,
            content: "NUMBA 4"
        }
    ],
    curr_indx = 0,
    timer     = setInterval(function () {
        if (curr_indx >= flip_opts.length) {
            curr_indx = 0;
        }
        $flipBox.flip(flip_opts[curr_indx]);
        curr_indx++;
    }, 3000);
```

fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/Ws6sS/

It's set on a timer

Comment: Nope. Look closely at how this works. It appends a new element with the same dimensions/background size, and then just animates the element into its self and back out again; then it removes its self and displays the next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Ohgodwhy -- Not possible.. "It appends a new element with the same dimensions/background size, and then just animates the element into its self and back out again; then it removes its self and displays the next element"